# Why is my CV question here duplicated on 'Solve Forum'?

Tags: discussion, policy, participation

I was doing an image search for other examples of something relating to a question I had already asked on Cross Validated, and came across this word-for-word copy:

https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/how-to-interpret-a-missing-data-combination-frequency-plot-e-g-vim-aggr.1476718/

CV original is here:

[How to interpret a missing data combination-frequency plot (e.g. VIM::aggr)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587209/how-to-interpret-a-missing-data-combination-frequency-plot-e-g-vimaggr)

Comment: There are sites that scrub the internet & repost SE content.  Given that everything is posted under CC policy, it may be legal if properly attributed.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/q/82763

Comment: An excellent rule is never to visit "forums" or other sites that only repost material, especially when it's unattributed.  That is *prima facie* evidence that they are dishonest, so why waste your time on them?

Comment: There was a mechanism to report sites to stackexchange that fail to abide by the license conditions; in the past I even used it at some point. I presume it still exists.

Comment: @Glen_b The mechanism is [the contact form](/contact). ?topic=10, though the extra boxes don't appear when I put that in the URL.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's it. When I manually choose the topic from the list, at least, I get these relevant boxes come up: 
**Link to the site reproducing Stack Exchange content** [...]   
**Link to the corresponding content on our site** [...]   
**Search terms** [...]   
**Please include anything else you find relevant (optional)**  [...]